# Linux FreeBSD shared object problem

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, freebsd, linker-errors

I am trying to build an application for freebsd which links to a shared object "share.so" built on linux. I also have freebsd linux compatible libraries under /usr/compat/linux/lib. I am able to compile my application. But while linking to "share.so" I am getting bunch of errors as share.so(built on linux) needs to access libraries under "/usr/compat/linux/lib". Is there a way to tell share.so to look into compat linux directory instead of /usr/lib/

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libstdc++.so.6, needed by sharedlib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

/usr/bin/ld: warning: libm.so.6, needed by sharedlib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

/usr/bin/ld: warning: libgcc_s.so.1, needed by sharedlib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpthread.so.0, needed by sharedlib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

These are the warnings I am getting. These versions are available in compat/linux/lib where as the /usr/lib contains lower versions. Here sharedlib.so is the .so files generated on linux

Comment: Please post your linker command (Makefile?) and any relevant errors

Comment: Hi Sam, I updated my question with the warnings I am getting. We actually have access to the source of sharedlib so we are compiling it for freebsd. But I would still like to know if you have any thoughts on how to get around this problem. for linking I am just giving path of the sharedlib -L /path/to/sharedlib. I also tried adding -L/usr/compat/linux/usr/lib to the command but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your [loader configuration](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/FreeBSD/ldconfig.8.html) to tell it to look in that directory for libraries.